# Estimating pose of one camera given another with known baseline

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I am a beginner when it comes to computer vision so I apologize in advance. Basically, the idea I am trying to code is that given two cameras that can simulate a multiple baseline stereo system; I am trying to estimate the pose of one camera given the other.

Looking at the same scene, I would incorporate some noise in the pose of the second camera, and given the clean image from camera 1, and slightly distorted/skewed image from camera 2, I would like to estimate the pose of camera 2 from this data as well as the known baseline between the cameras. I have been reading up about homography matrices and related implementation in opencv, but I am just trying to get some suggestions about possible approaches. Most of the applications of the homography matrix that I have seen talk about stitching or overlaying images, but here I am looking for a six degrees of freedom attitude of the camera from that.

It'd be great if someone can shed some light on these questions too: Can an approach used for this be extended to more than two cameras? And is it also possible for both the cameras to have some 'noise' in their pose, and yet recover the 6dof attitude at every instant?

Comment: I wouldn't apologize for being a beginner. Everybody once was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's clear up your question first. I guess You are looking for the pose of the camera relative to another camera location. This is described by Homography only for pure camera rotations. For General motion that includes translation this is described by rotation and translation matrices. If the fields of view of the cameras overlap the task can be solved with structure from motion which still estimates only 5 dof. This means that translation is estimated up to scale. If there is a chessboard with known dimensions in the cameras' field of view you can easily solve for 6dof by running a PnP algorithm. Of course, cameras should be calibrated first. Finally, in 2008 Marc Pollefeys came up with an idea how to estimate 6 dof from two moving cameras with non-overlapping fields of view without using any chess boards. To give you more detail please tell a bit for the intended appljcation you are looking for.

Comment: Hi Vlad, my intended application is in robotics: imagine two UAVs (quadcopters for example) equipped with monocular cameras, calibrated looking at the same scene (like a chessboard visible from both) spaced apart by a known distance. If we assume the quadcopters are hovering in the air, this is usually achieved through GPS based control and can be flaky/noisy, and this noise ultimately affects the camera position too. If we assume the position of quad1 is noise free and stable, and quad2 is noisy, the question is can I estimate the noise on quad2 and subsequently use it to stabilize the quad?

Comment: spacing by known distance doesn’t mean you know the relative rotation of quadcopters and the rotation will affect images a lot. I still don’e understand stabilization problem since any motion in monocular camera can be attributed to noise and thus there is no need in stereo. If you want one of the quad to mirror the motion of another with some baseline you have to restore 3D, change the viewpoint and re-project 3D into quad2 and see how the camera image is different form that projection. This uses Structure from Motion which is not trivial algorithm see below.

Comment: Thanks for the info and the link. The reason why I had two quads in the scenario is because, if the end goal is for instance to map an object in 3D using structure from motion with quadcopters (could be more than two if needed), my idea was to perhaps use information from one of the cameras to "assist" the stabilization of the other camera(s)..

Comment: it seems that you would benefit more from having two cameras on a single flying device than one on each flying devices.